# Unterminated JSX contents in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I downloaded the Calendar model form [react-native-calendar-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select)

package

```
npm install --save react-native-calendar-select
```

source code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Calendar from 'react-native-calendar-select';


class YourComponent extends Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    startDate: new Date(2017, 6, 12),  
    endDate: new Date(2017, 8, 2)
  };
  this.confirmDate = this.confirmDate.bind(this);
  this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
}
// when confirm button is clicked, an object is conveyed to outer component
// contains following property:
// startDate [Date Object], endDate [Date Object]
// startMoment [Moment Object], endMoment [Moment Object]
confirmDate({startDate, endDate, startMoment, endMoment}) {
  this.setState({
    startDate,
    endDate
  });
}
openCalendar() {
  this.calendar && this.calendar.open();
}
// in render function
render() {
  // It's an optional property, I use this to show the structure of customI18n object.
  let customI18n = {
    'w': ['', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    'weekday': ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    'text': {
      'start': 'Check in',
      'end': 'Check out',
      'date': 'Date',
      'save': 'Confirm',
      'clear': 'Reset'
    },
    'date': 'DD / MM'  // date format
  };
  // optional property, too.
  let color = {
    subColor: '#f0f0f0'
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Open Calendar" onPress={this.openCalendar}>
      <Calendar
        i18n="en"
        ref={(calendar) => {this.calendar = calendar;}}
        customI18n={customI18n}
        color={color}
        format="YYYYMMDD"
        minDate="20170510"
        maxDate="20180312"
        startDate={this.state.startDate}
        endDate={this.state.endDate}
        onConfirm={this.confirmDate}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I run it I get this error
This is the original code from the website I can't find where the problem is

[image: emulator error]

> it's a calendar date picker, I copied the original code from the [npm
>   website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select) and placed the code in a class class component
>
> > please can you help me to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close your `<Button>` above your calendar. Like: `<Button title="Open Calendar" onPress={this.openCalendar} />`

Comment: it says unexpected token (70:0)

Comment: Berglonn bu t it doesn't tell which token

Answer (score 0):

The button tag in your code has an unterminated tag. Try this

```
<Button title="Open Calendar" onPress={this.openCalendar} />
```